# Excel: average non-continuous range with blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have received an Excel file with the question to make a formula that calculates the average of a range that is not continuous, and when there are zero or blank values, that the formula doesn't take in account those cells.

The Excel file does look like this:
[image]

We have to calculate an average for the morning (I2, I4, I6, I8, I10, I12 and I14) and evening 
(I3, I5, I7, I9, I11, I13 and I15). So I already figured out that I have to make a named range for this:
[image]

Now I have found several sites which are telling me that I have to use AVERAGEIF, or COUNTIF, SUMIF,... but I'm always getting "#value".

[image]

What is the solution to do this calculation?

Edit:
The file can be downloaded here: http://goo.gl/7k14Rm (File > download)

Comment: It might be excel dialect, but your `averageif` is correct for my version. Try using the cells rather than the named range, see if that works first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AVERAGEIFS` perhaps?

```
=AVERAGEIFS(I2:I15;I2:I15;"<>0";C2:C15;"Ochtend")
```

This is for `Ochtend`.

For `Avond`:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(I2:I15;I2:I15;"<>0";C2:C15;"Avond")
```

So that it will calculate the average of `I2:I15` only for values not zero and for those corresponding to `Avond`.